# applying css using class name or ID attribute of html element in reactjs component

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am using UI component made of bootstrap which uses class name on the html element to define its look and feel. I have written html inside component class Home.js as follows :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import style from './css/main.css';

export default class Home extends Component{

  render(){
    return(
      <div class="wrapper" >

        <nav id="sidebar" >
            <div class="sidebar-header">
              <h3>Collapsible Sidebar</h3>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components" >
              <li class="active" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

              <li>
                <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Pages</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                </ul>

                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
          <div id="content">
              <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
                Toggle Sidebar
              </button>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have defined all css styling in main.css and it is been imported in home.js as can be seen in the source code above. My main.css if as following:

```
.header{
  background: #F8F8F8;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: right;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}
```

But I see, styles are not been applied as expected using class name or ID. Is there anyway where I can use existing UI component in reactjs without much change As I want to achieve in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

Your component should use className and not class.

Since, in JSX, class and for are invalid attributes, we have been asked to use className and htmlFor

Comment: But in that case how to use bootstrap elements which are rendered using class names and ID values .

Comment: can you give an example of which kind of bootstrap UI elements you are mentioning in this context?

Comment: I am using <sidebar> as been shown in the above home.js

Comment: rather than saying  <nav id="sidebar" > we can say  <nav className="sidebar" > and replace your css selector to use className  #sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
} to .sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing but it is time consuming ans looks like if we have to use reactjs then we can not use bootstrap if we have to do all this.  .sidebar.active will not work. We need to change this to .sidebar_active

Comment: I am not sure about .sidebar_active, but yes if we are using react, if we need to apply classes, it would be better if we do it as className. However I am pretty sure that even if we have id, we can give styles based on id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165660/discussion-between-g-s-and-hitesh).

Answer (score 0):

Your style now is js object so in order to pass value from that object you need to write:

```
 <div className={style.wrapper} >
```

Also you should use **className** instead of class in React JSX